# How Poco Use in MVC3 with example?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, poco

I am new to POCO and all this MVC stufffs.

Reading some articals about POCO on google, but not having exact idea may be lack of my knowledge about it or not proper examples i got.

Can any one please explain me how to use this "POCO" stuffs in my MVC project.

it would be great if any vidoe link for POCO to learn

Comment: Reading articles is not enough. Trying to use the technology is a must. Once you use a technology you will find real questions to ask. Your comment to the deleted answer was just example how bad your question is because it is too broad.

Comment: true, and that is why i ask for an example or an You tube Video, at least to know from core, you may be right on your place, but i am not asking silly question, if you think you should come with proper example and then should comment me.

Comment: Of course, you are a lot technical than me, but according to me you should be clarify (more clarify) to get team work on stack overflow. Thanks a lot, please do not make such a rude comment on the question unless you have proper answer for beginner who want to start (experiment) something new.

Comment: I don't say that the question is silly. I just explain why it will be closed. It is too broad and it is not specific programming problem - it asks for tutorial or video.

Answer (score 1):

The POCO term is used to be able to tell if the object has any side effects and the term is usually used together with OR/M layers.

An object which is a POCO have no dependencies to your ORM layer or anything else. If you serialize it and then deserialize it will still look the same.

non-pocos can be used to be able to add support for lazy loading or be able to track the entity. The normal approach is that the object is either inherited from your regular class (a proxy) or that it has the features from start.